# Yield with delegate

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Iterator Function Read(Of T)(ByVal sql As String, ByVal make As Func(Of IDataReader, T), ParamArray ByVal parms() As Object) As IEnumerable(Of T)
            Using connection = CreateConnection()
                Using command = CreateCommand(sql, connection, parms)
                    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                        Do While reader.Read()
                            Yield make(reader) --line 7
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Function

Private Shared Make As Func(Of IDataReader, Member) =
            Function(reader) _
                New Member() With {
                    .MemberId = Extensions.AsId(reader("MemberId")),
                    .Email = Extensions.AsString(reader("Email")),
                    .CompanyName = Extensions.AsString(reader("CompanyName")),
                    .City = Extensions.AsString(reader("City")),
                    .Country = Extensions.AsString(reader("Country"))
                }
```

Please see line 7.  Make populates an object of type Member with values from the data reader row.  I have read the following documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx.  The documentation does not seem to explain what happens when you use a delegate i.e. Yield make(datareader), rather than Yield return datareader.  Is control passed back to the calling function as well as the delegate (Make)?

Answer (score 0):

`Make(reader)` is a shortcut for `Make.Invoke(reader)`. I.e., you

- invoke the delegate, passing `reader` as a parameter, which yields a value of type `Member`.
- Then, you return that value using `Yield`.

It is equivalent to :

```
...
    Do While reader.Read()
        Dim myMember As Member = make(reader)
        Yield myMember
    Loop
...
```

PS: If you get a compile-time error in your code (you don't say so in your question): This is due to the fact that your method is declared to return an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, when in fact it returns an `IEnumerable(Of Member)`.

Comment: Where are the objects of type member put after the make delegate has run? I expected control to be passed back to the function that called read after make runs, but this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @w0051977: If `Member` is a class: on the heap. If it's a struct: probably on the stack. That should not make a difference, though. Whether and how control is returned might depend on the calling code: If you just call `Dim x = Read()`, control will be returned *immediately* (even before executing the first line of Read). If you call `Dim x = Read().ToList()`, `Read` will be executed fully before returning. If you use `For Each x in Read()`, execution of `Read` will be in lock-step with your loop.

Comment: @w0051977: I do believe that you are on the wrong track here. Your problem lies elsewhere, it is unrelated to your use of a delegate (try replacing the delegate with a regular function to convince yourself).